# Is there a good sans serif condensed safe font for web?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I'm looking for a web safe font that looks like this:

[image: Convenience font img]

Of course I can find tons of fonts which look like this that are available, but they are not web safe. I need a common font (e.g.Arial, Times New Roman, etc.) because I intend to use the font for my website, for headings.

Comment: Check out [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) they have some thicker fonts (Gudea, Francois One, Istok Web, etc.) and they are made to use on websites.

Comment: If you want something common, you need look no further than the nearest Windows PC. I don't think Windows comes with anything that condensed: Arial Narrow is probably the closest. Best thing to do is to use a webfont so you know exactly what your users see.

Comment: Why limit yourself to web safe fonts anymore?  It's 2013 and web fonts are now well-supported, and these of course don't require the user to have them pre-installed.

Comment: @Andrew Leach, Arial Narrow is not installed with Windows, it is only installed with Microsoft Office.

Comment: @thomasrutter Because web fonts cause layout shifts (or delayed rendering). That looks ugly and feels jarring and annoying, and thus looks unprofessional. (Most current websites have considerable design problems, including websites of huge companies.)

Answer (score 7):

[Open Sans Condensed](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed)

[image: Open Sans]

Multiple weights, and a non-condensed version available as well.

Comment: That's a nice pick!

Comment: what will be fallback font for this?

Answer (score 2):

[League Gothic](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic) is a great condensed "headline" font. It's a little more in the Gothic camp than Geometric (which is what your sample leans towards in my opinion), but I think you'll like it a lot.

[image]

EDIT: @thomasrutter made a comment below about the nature of "web safe." While this is not a Core Font that is naturally sitting on the vast majority of PCs, this is a freely available and embeddable font, so as long as you get the right font files ([FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) has a good resource for this), you'll get compatibility on virtually every browser that's used today (even IE, since version 4!).

Comment: People have different meanings when they say "web safe", but if they mean fonts that are part of Microsoft's Core Fonts for the Web and/or pre-installed on most users' computers, this is not web-safe.

Comment: @thomasrutter - Good point. I edited my answer to elaborate why I believe this to be "web safe".

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't look exactly the same, I'd recommend **Impact** as a great font that most computers will have installed already (Impact has been distributed with Microsoft Windows since Windows 98).

[image]

But there's no reason why you wouldn't use google webfonts, as mentioned in the comments, so I'd probably go in that direction.

You might find these interesting:

- [Best 20 webfonts from Google Web Fonts and @font-face embedding](http://www.awwwards.com/best-20-webfonts-from-google-web-fonts-and-font-face-embedding.html)
- [CONDENSED FONTS: THE GOOD, THE BAD, THE UGLY](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/20/condensed-fonts-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 'Franklin Gothic Medium' and 'Arial Narrow' in that order. See https://www.cssfontstack.com/ for the numbers on how safe they are.

Comment: This is actually the most useful answer, b/c all the others are mentioning custom fonts, not preinstalled on most computers. And many thanks for the cssfontstack link - was able to find some fallbacks there

Answer (score 0):

**[Roboto Condensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed?standard-styles=&query=roboto%20)**
While this is not a "web-safe font" it can be very easily included on your page.

The snippet below shows how to include Roboto And Roboto Condensed asynchronously. (Taken from [here](https://pagespeedchecklist.com/asynchronous-google-fonts)).

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" onload="this.onload=null;this.removeAttribute('media');" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap">
```